# Magento Get Products Original Data - Select Attribute Text Not ID

Tags: magento

I have an observer that runs at *catalog_product_save_after*. I'm checking to see if certain attributes have changed. This is easy done by like this;

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');

$old = $_product->getOrigData('text_attribute');
$new = $_product->getData('text_attribute');

if($new != $old){ 
    // text_attribute has changed... 
}
```

Now I need to get the products original text value (Not the ID) of a select attribute.

I have tried;

```
echo $_product->getOrigData('select_attribute'); // outputs int like 8947, I need the text!
echo $_product->getOrigAttributeText('select_attribute'); // Didn't work but it was worth a try.
```

Is there a simple way of achieving this or do I need to use the int returned when using *getOrigData* to look up the text value?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
$oldText = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
                ->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'text_attribute')
                ->getFrontend()
                ->getOption($old);

$newText = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
                ->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'text_attribute')
                ->getFrontend()
                ->getOption($new);
```